# sending an image with protobuf

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

With my message i want to send an image i read [here](http://groups.google.com/group/protobuf/browse_thread/thread/5cfa566d44b27e9a) that its possible to send an image with bytes. So i converted my image to a bytestring. Now iam stuck at making form that array a bytestring so i can use it. I was loocking troug the documentation of google and found the ByteString class so i tryed calling the construct but thats private. so is there any method of making my bytearray into a bytestring?

Comment: just found the awnser needed to use ByteString.copyFrom();